# Do not parse shortcode in CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

I have CPT where i do not want to parse shortccode in it's content (using the_content() function). I can use remove_filter to remove default filters for shortcode. but how will i determine that i am removing filter only for my desire CPT?

I have a shortcode [my-custom-shortcode] which i am using in a page. This shortcode use WP_Query and outputting CPT posts. I do not want to parse shortcode inside this CPT posts.

Should i change shortcode with dummy content before shortcode parse hook and replace back after? OR should i remove default filter for shortcode just before my CPT output and again add default filter for shortcodes after my CPT output done?

Or is there any better option?

EDIT:
My shortcode looks like this

```
add_shortcode( 'my-custom-shortcode', 'my_custom_function' );
function my_custom_function(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'my-cpt',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'order'=> 'ASC'
     );
    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    ob_start();

    if( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        $posts->the_post();
            the_content(); //Here i do not want to parse (any) shortcode
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: Instead of disabling the filter, you could update your Shortcode `function` so that `if ( 'your-cpt' === get_post_type() ) { return ''; }` - i.e. do/output nothing. I mean, if you could modify the Shortcode `function` code.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me. I have updated my question with code. Inside my shortcode content i do not want to parse any shortcode.

Comment: Thank you. I have already mentioned that in my question. But sometimes plugins changes this hook priority. That was my concern. Also is parsing shortcode cause any security issue (I am accepting content of this CPT from users)?

Comment: So if I now understand it correctly, you don't want *your* Shortcode to be run in the custom posts loop; right? (Because I know, that would end up with a never-ending loop..) (Sorry, I did not see your comment coming, so I removed my previous comment.)

Comment: `is parsing shortcode cause any security issue` - yes, it could. So you should use the [`shortcode_parse_atts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_parse_atts) function, and always [sanitize/escape user inputs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data). E.g. apply `esc_url()` on URL addresses.

Comment: I do not want to parse **any** shortcode inside my CPT content. So your previous comment was right (`remove_filter( 'the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11);` ) But i see some plugin changes this hook priority, that will invalid this remove_filter.

Comment: I see. Very sorry. I wish I could undelete *that comment*.. =) But one thing you could try to overcome the issue with those plugins, is.. temporarily change the global `$shortcode_tags` variable *after you copy it*. We can talk via chat, if you want. Alternatively, don't use *those* plugins.. eheh.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77292/discussion-between-shamim-hasan-and-sally-cj).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question for future reference for others who want this behavior

**If you want to show shortcode as plain text without parsing follow this procedure**

```
add_shortcode( 'my-custom-shortcode', 'my_custom_function' );
function my_custom_function(){
    global $shortcode_tags;
    $tags = $shortcode_tags;
    $shortcode_tags = array(); //empty global shortcode tags

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'my-cpt',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'order'=> 'ASC'
     );
    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    ob_start();

    if( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        $posts->the_post();
            the_content(); //Here i do not want to parse (any) shortcode
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    $shortcode_tags = $tags //reset tags to global variable
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

**If you want to strip shortcode without parsing follow this procedure**

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_remove_shortcode' );
function my_remove_shortcode( $content ) {
    if( get_post_type() == 'my-cpt' ) {
        $content = strip_shortcodes( $content ); // strip all shortcodes
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something like this-

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_303180_remove_shortcode' );
function wpse_303180_remove_shortcode( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if( get_post_type( $post ) == 'my-cpt' ) {
        remove_shortcode( 'my-custom-shortcode' );
        // remove_all_shortcodes(); // to remove all shortcodes
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But as i mentioned in my question i am using my shortcode inside a page. So your if check will fail in this condition.

Comment: Just updated it.

Comment: Just updated my answer. It'll now prevent from parsing the shortcode in given post_type's content. Please check.

Comment: Thank you again. But both [remove_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_shortcode/) and [remove_all_shortcodes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_all_shortcodes/) remove shortcode from global. So any content comes after my CPT will also lose its shortcode. We could use [strip_shortcodes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/strip_shortcodes/) but that will be resource intensive as well as strip shortcode itself. So i used like https://github.com/shamim2883/front-end-pm/commit/fd495b0cbf2f2066b899558f3bbf9786c2080d57

Comment: Did you test my code?

Comment: Yes, it is overriding shortcode global. So if any shortcode comes after my CPT those shortcode will not parse. For clarification or see test code you can chat with me.